# "File unavailable (eg, file not found, no access)" while installing flashplugin from FreeBDS ftp site

Tags: freebsd, firefox, adobe-flash

I tried with this tutorial:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/desktop-browsers.html

but an error occurs in this part:

```
/usr/ports/www/linux-f10-flashplugin11 # make install clean
...
fetch: ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/flashplugin/11.2r202.327/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz: File unavailable (eg, file not found, no access)
=> Could not fetch it - please try to retrieve this
=> Port manually into /usr/ports/distfiles/flashplugin/11.2r202.327 and try again.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make [1]: stopped in /usr/ports/www/linux-f10-flashplugin11
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/www/linux-f10-flashplugin11
```

Contents of the file /etc/portsnap.conf

```
# $FreeBSD: release/10.0.0/etc/portsnap.conf 255878 2013-09-26 10:33:15Z cperciva $

# Default directory where compressed snapshots are stored.
# WORKDIR=/var/db/portsnap

# Default location of the ports tree (target for "update" and "extract").
# PORTSDIR=/usr/ports

# Server or server pool from which to fetch updates.  You can change
# this to point at a specific server if you want, but in most cases
# using a "nearby" server won't provide a measurable improvement in
# performance.
SERVERNAME=portsnap.FreeBSD.org

# Trusted keyprint.  Changing this is a Bad Idea unless you've received
# a PGP-signed email from <security-officer@FreeBSD.org> telling you to
# change it and explaining why.
KEYPRINT=9b5feee6d69f170e3dd0a2c8e469ddbd64f13f978f2f3aede40c98633216c330

# Example of ignoring parts of the ports tree.  If you know that you
# absolutely will not need certain parts of the tree, this will save
# some bandwidth and disk space.  See the manual page for more details.
#
# WARNING: Working with an incomplete ports tree is not supported and
# can cause problems due to missing dependencies.  If you have REFUSE
# directives and experience problems, remove them and update your tree
# before asking for help on the mailing lists.
#
# REFUSE arabic chinese french german hebrew hungarian japanese
# REFUSE korean polish portuguese russian ukrainian vietnamese

# List of INDEX files to build and the DESCRIBE file to use for each
INDEX INDEX-8 DESCRIBE.8
INDEX INDEX-9 DESCRIBE.9
INDEX INDEX-10 DESCRIBE.10
```

Comment: did you try to update ports ?

Comment: # portsnap fetch
Looking up portsnap.FreeBSD.org mirrors... none found.
Fetching public key from portsnap.FreeBSD.org... key has incorrect hash.
No mirrors remaining, giving up.

Comment: I am newbie in FreeBSD, is there another way to update the ports?

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD? What is the content of /etc/portsnap.conf?

Comment: I edited the question and added the contents of portsnap.conf, would not fit in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

When you travel to `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/`, you will see the README.txt file:

> Our distfiles cache has been moved to:
>
> http://distcache.FreeBSD.org/ports-distfiles/
>
> distfiles can be fetched by name from there, as specified
> in the corresponding port that uses it.

So, just update/change the port that you are using.